# Calculating actual humidity using sy-hs 220 humidity sensor

Tags: arduino, humidity

I am getting following output from sy-hs 220 humidity sensor.

```
466
466
467
466
466
```

i.e. approximate 466. How would I convert it to actual humidity?
As from datasheet I came to know that this sensor outputs DC voltage. Some calculations are given in datasheet, but I am unable to calculate it.
Link to datasheet [Source](http://www.apollounion.com/Upload/DownFiles/SY-HS-220.pdf). (Please see the standard characteristic in datasheet) I am new to this field please help.

Comment: What are you measuring from the humidity sensor ,voltage ? can you provide the schematic ?

Comment: I just want to measure actual humidity. What ever analog values I got that I have posted. Not sure how to calculate

Comment: The answer to the linked question has a python equivalent to the Arduino map() function @DaveTweed mentioned below.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969240/mapping-a-range-of-values-to-another?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what hardware you are using. Let's assume that you're using an Arduino.

- Arduino returns ADC values from 0 to 1024 for 0 to 5V.
- The humidity sensor returns from 1 to 3V which is 205 to 614 in ADC values.

So using an inbuilt function map(), we get this code:

```
    int val = analogRead(0);
    val = map(val, 205, 614, 30, 90);
```

Comment: actually I am not using arduino. I have xbee which is sensing the values after interval of 10 sec and giving to serial port of debian and using pythonXbee library i am extracting the values. I didn't got the use of map()

Comment: I will try with arduino and let you know the results. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet, the humidity sensor is linear & operates between 30-90%RH.

Hence as long as the humidity value is between 30-90%RH, this formula is applied:

```
Humidity = (ADC Voltage in mV) * (330)
```

In order to convert the ADC value it into the actual humidity value

```
Humidity = (ADC Value - Minimum ADC Value) * (Maximum Humidity Value - Minimum Humidity Value) / (Maximum ADC Value - Minimum ADC Value) + Minimum Humidity Value
```

You can find the Arduino Example Code for SY-HS-220/SL-HS-220 in the link below:
https://github.com/jonathanrjpereira/SY-HS-220-Humidity-Temperature-Sensor